# Nested events tier 2 does not trigger

Tags: vb.net, events, visual-studio-2013

I have hit a roadblock that I cant seem to get past. I have a groupbox that uses a mousehover event. and within that groupbox, have  five click events on five labels (one event per label to clarify). My problem is this:

It apprears to me that the mousehover event is killing the click event, thus never lets it trigger. Is there a way to make the hoverevent fire only once and deactivate until the mouse leaves the groupbox area?

find code for both events below:

```
Private Sub GroupBox1_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GroupBox1.MouseHover
    If GroupBox1.Height = 18 Then
        GroupBox1.Height = 180
        GroupBox2.Height = 18
        GroupBox3.Height = 18
        GroupBox4.Height = 18
        GroupBox5.Height = 18
        GroupBox1.Top = 12
        GroupBox2.Top = 198
        GroupBox3.Top = 222
        GroupBox4.Top = 246
        GroupBox5.Top = 270
        GroupBox1.Text = "Session 1 (+)"
        GroupBox2.Text = "Session 2 (-)"
        GroupBox3.Text = "Session 3 (-)"
        GroupBox4.Text = "Session 4 (-)"
        GroupBox5.Text = "Session 5 (-)"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub HTS1S1_Click(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles HTS1S1.Click
    If HTS1S1.Text = 1 Then
        HTS1S1.Text = 0
        ATS1SA.Text = 1
    ElseIf HTS1S1.Text = 0 Then
        HTS1S1.Text = 1
        ATS1SA.Text = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Any help would be highly appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: turn on option strict; `If HTS1S1.Text = 1` is comparing a string to an integer.  (events are not nested, either)

Comment: I did this but get and converted the strings to doubles. I now get a new error: "Method 'Private Sub HTS1S1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)' cannot handle event 'Public Event Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)' because they do not have a compatible signature."

Comment: the msg gives you the solution: it should be `e As EventArgs` - the designer will create event handlers for you (with the correct args) - that one looks like you pasted it or something - dont do that

Comment: Apologies for that. changing to `e As EventArgs` removed the error but still did not execute the click event. It also forces me to change `HTS1S1.Text = 1` to `CDbl(HTS1S1) = 1`. Is this what is causing the issue?

Comment: `CDbl(HTS1S1)` is illegal so Option Strict must be (still?) off.  Set a breakpoint and see if the event is fired, then step thru it to see why it doesnt act like you want.

Comment: Its not firing at all. I tested it on the mousehover event and it triggered the breakpoint but on the click event, nothing triggers the break.

Comment: hovering over the groupbox will not trigger a Label click event - that happens only when you Click the label

Comment: I know. what I meant with the previous comment was that I just needed to check if the breakpoint is reached, so I tested it on the hover event (I am not used to using breakpoints). I moved the breakpoint to the label click but did not reach the break.

Comment: @Plutonix I found the issue. Amateur mistake from my side. I looked at the label again and noticed that I had it disabled. the backcolor is the same shade as a disabled control, thus missed the possibility completely.

Comment: yes, disabled controls do not get events

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I learnt something new today. I only knew about option explicit and not option strict. Very helpful option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, amateur mistake from my side. I looked at the label again and noticed that I had it disabled. the backcolor is the same shade as a disabled control, thus missed the possibility completely.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: Noted. I actually thought it was to close the thread. That is why I posted to it with the actual fix (Error correction), but I will remember that for future posts.

Comment: @StevendeBeer: sorry for the confusion that others have created. This is in fact the correct way to mark the question as answered by posting the solution by yourself. See the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for an official explanation that explicitly allows questioners to answer their own question.